# Rust and loader paths (@rpath, @loader_path) on OS X

Tags: macos, rust, rust-cargo, rpath

I'm trying to solve a problem with foreign library loading with Rust.

**Inputs:**

I have an executable `rtest` and a dylib `libcpp2rs.dylib`. The library is linked to the executable through FFI:

```
#[link(name="cpp2rs")]
extern { ... }
```

My `build.rs` file (I'm passing an extra argument with `libcpp2rs.dylib` location):

```
pub fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=./cpplib/bin");
}
```

And my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "rtest"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["astavonin"]
build = "build.rs"
rpath = true
[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.10"
```

And I use `cargo build` command for compilation.

**Outputs:**

`otool` shows me that library will be loaded by `RPATH`:

```
> otool -L rtest
rtest:
@rpath/libcpp2rs.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

But at the same time there is no `LC_LPATH` section in executable:

```
> otool -l rtest | grep LC_RPATH
>
```

And it leads my application to a loading error:

```
> ./rtest 
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcpp2rs.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/astavonin/projects/Tests/rtest/target/debug/./rtest
  Reason: image not found
zsh: trace trap  ./rtest
```

This issue can be fixed by `install_name_tool` usage, but I prefer do not introduce additional steps into compilation process.

1. Is it possible (and how) to change loading type from @rpath to @loader_path with `cargo` configurations/build script?
2. Is it possible to pass @rpath value to `cargo`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include where `libcpp2rs.dylib` is located, how you are informing Rust of where it is, and how you are building the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some researches around I've found that the actual problem is `libcpp2rs.dylib` ID:

```
> otool -L cpplib/bin/libcpp2rs.dylib 
cpplib/bin/libcpp2rs.dylib:
    @rpath/libcpp2rs.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

`rustc` uses a dylib ID as a reference for linkage type and if you'd like to change linkage type for a library to `@loader_path` for example, you have to fix dylib ID. It should looks like:

```
@loader_path/libcpp2rs.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```